# Default download folder for draw.io

Tags: download, app.diagrams.net

Can I change the default folder that draw.io saves its' xml files, and and downloaded image files, to? At the moment they keep going to my Downloads folder which doesn't work for me.

Comment: The download location (assuming that you're saving them to your local device) is a function of your web browser, not that of the draw.io site.  You should be able to change your browser's default download location in its configuration.

Answer (score 2):

It depends, see below. Some browsers don't provide the permissions to perform a folder selection when downloading a file, browsers are very restrictive about file system access.

For these browsers, the only option here is to change the download folder in the browser options while using draw.

If you use Chrome 83 or later draw.io supports Native File API, which will open your operating system save dialog, allowing you to save anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the default folder cannot be changed, in Firefox and IE (not Chrome), you can choose which folder you want to save in when you click "Save as..."